# Get secondary bluetooth gatt service android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Fetch android secondary bluetooth gatt service from bluetooth android API's.

Currently below is the code where we fetch ble services :

```
public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
                List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices = mBluetoothGatt.getServices();
                Log.e("onServicesDiscovered", "Services count: "+gattServices.size());

                BluetoothGattService bleServ = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString("22222222-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"));

                for (BluetoothGattService gattService : gattServices) {
                    String serviceUUID = gattService.getUuid().toString();
                    Log.e("onServicesDiscovered", "Service uuid "+serviceUUID);
                }
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
            }
        }
```

Even tried fetching exclusively the secondary service but it returns null object :

```
 BluetoothGattService bleServ = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString("22222222-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"));
```

Can someone point any pointers how to search secondary ble service in Android.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this method: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattService.html#getIncludedServices() on a primary service.

Comment: Thanks for the response Emil. Even i had the same discussion with our bluetooth stack developer. Can you provide with inputs how to make a secondary service part of a primary service on a ble peripheral device. Our ble team is using BlueZ stack and following is the link they are referring to for creation of services on the ble device      https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/gatt-api.txt

Comment: Seems like it isn't implemented in BlueZ "array{object} Includes [read-only]: Not implemented". Do you really need secondary services? Can't you use primary service?

Comment: There is a requirement to not expose certain services to all the devices for connectivity. Only the device which is allowed for connection with ble peripheral will be able to communicate to the other secondary services.